# Jupyter notebook kernel disconnecting / dead after sometime and cannot reconnect to amazon EC2 instance and complete ( currently running) operation.

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, jupyter-notebook, winscp, jupyter-kernel

1. When I connect to EC2 instance via Mobaxterm, after some period of time my jupyter notebook's kernel loses connection.
2. And some highly time-consuming operations /(Currently running tasks) are required to be re-performed again and again and are never-ending (This repeats each and every time).
3. I'm closing the notebook and restarting, so I can gain a connection to the kernel because it doesn't reconnect and I had to go through the process again and again when it dies eventually.
4. It also shows SSL error, wrong version number sometimes before disconnecting.

Answer (score 1):

I have also faced a similar problem. I solved it with the help of '[tmux](https://github.com/tmux/tmux/wiki)'. 
I followed these steps:

1. I installed 'tmux' in my machine in the AWS instance.

[Actually, it came preinstalled with the AMI I had been using on the EC2 instance.]

3. I created a 'tmux' session simply by entering the command: `tmux`
4. Then I ran necessary commands to run the `Jupyter server` or `Jupyter notebook`
5. To close the terminal, I used this command: (i) `ctrl + b`, (ii) `d`

[Please notice, the session will continue running on the EC2 instance until you close the instance or close the `jupyter server` or the `jupyter notebook`].

5. To connect to the session again, I used the command: `tmux attach`
6. To finally kill the 'tmux' session when I am done, I used the command: `tmux kill-session`

Answer (score 1):

Just use `nohup`. This should be the builtin tool in all Linux machines.

So you should do: `nohup jupyter notebook > output.txt`

And then you can safely terminate the console session without worrying about killing the notebook.

Comment: this actually helped a lot, thanks